# contenteditable="false" attribute not working on dynamically created span in angular 10

Tags: javascript, angular

> I have added span element dynamically in .ts file where I have added contenteditable attribute but when it gets rendered on web page this attribute is didnt get appeared in tag. I have added as
> `newHTML +=` &nbsp<span class='taggedUser' [contenteditable]='false'>${taggedUserName}&nbsp ` .I want to use to this attribute.
> Reason : I want to highlight the user in text and for that I am adding span and its css.

Answer (score 0):

how are you adding newHTML to your components html file?
Are you using the innerHTML attribute like so:

```
[innerHTML]=newHTML
```

**UPDATE:**

Angular has a security mechanism to prevent XSS for example,
So sometimes when you try to add something to your html as a string in runtime it strips some properties/styling from the html.

A simple example would be something like:

```
constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.newHTML += this.sanitize(`&nbsp<span class='taggedUser' [contenteditable]='false'>${taggedUserName}&nbsp `)
}

sanitize(htmlStr: string): SafeHtml {
   return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlStr);
}
```

https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer

Comment: have you tried to sanitize the html string using Angulars DomSanitizer?

Comment: Not really can you add some example here or link maybe?